# Is it valid/recommended to use string literals as the result of an expression using the ternary operator?

Tags: c, conditional-operator, string-literals

Is the following code valid/good practice in C?

```
int x = 1;
printf(x == 1 ? "%d second elapsed" : "%d seconds elapsed", x);
```

It compiles fine, so I assume it is fine (also since it is just syntactical sugar for an if-else block), but if anyone has some additional insight, I would appreciate it, thank you.

P.S., I assume the same goes for C++?

Comment: Yes, it’s fine.

Comment: I'd perhaps do it `printf("%d second%s elapsed", x, x == 1 ? "" : "s");` but, yeah, it's fine.

Comment: @TedLyngmo ahhh now that's a much cleverer solution, thanks

Comment: an alternative: `printf("%d second%s elapsed", x, "s" + (x == 1));`

Comment: @phuclv :-) nice. Just in case the compiler isn't bright enough to do that saving itself

Comment: @TedLyngmo in case the compiler is not smart enough you can even use `printf("%d second%s", x, "s elapsed" + (x == 1));`

Comment: @phuclv Hmm, that'll save 1 byte just like the first one if I read it correctly.

Comment: Of course, translators won't thank you if you make the code too clever!

Comment: One potential problem with the original code is that since `printf`'s first argument isn't constant, the compiler may have a harder time checking it for validity.  In fact I believe some compilers warn about, and some style guides prohibit, non-constant `printf` format arguments for this reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

Opinionated: After wading though tons of code written by programmers writing kernels, drivers and misc. utility programs that are usually considered "good", I think the consensus is that "it's fine". Not only is it safe - it can also be made easily readable.

A small, non-opinionated, note: Compilers are allowed to make string literals overlap. If you have two string literals, `"Hello world"` and `"world"` and compile your program will full optimization, you may find that the pointer to `'w'` in `"world"` is actually within the `"Hello world"` string literal, since they are both valid, null-terminated strings. Example:

```
ptr1
 |
 V
 hello world\0
       ^
       |
      ptr2
```

However, that optimization cannot be applied to strings like yours, since the different part is in the *middle* of the string literal.

I therefore suggest:

```
printf("%d second%s elapsed", x, x == 1 ? "" : "s");
```

Another opinion of mine is that doing it like this also makes it easier to read.

Comment: My first thought was “that can’t be right”. But I can’t get godbolt to overlap the literals either way. May I ask why use of the ternary operator would obviate folding string literals?

Comment: @Dúthomhas The use of the ternary operator doesn't prevent it, it's the actual string literals that _can_ overlap that sets the limits. The string literal `"foo"` and `"oo"` has an obvious overlap. `"foo"` and `"fo"` ... nope. `"fo"` would here need its own space since it needs the terminating null terminator.

Comment: “That detail makes your version of using the ternary operator sub-optimal, since that optimization can't be done.” — Ah, your sentence structure confused me. The pointer to `'w'` points to the string `"world"`, which should not be bothered by the ternary operator. But you mean that the fragment _in the middle of the string_ cannot be optimized — which has nothing to do with the ternary operator. I would reword to separate those two thoughts.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I will look at it after Zombie-galore-night here. If you want, suggest an edit and I'll have something to go on.

Comment: Done. Enjoy the zombies!

Comment: Very interesting answer, thanks! I had no idea that compilers could make string literals overlap during optimization. I'll definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Thanks! All zombies are now dealt  with. I thank you for your improvement of my answer and just had to make a small adjustment. Even they are in separate `if` statements, in different parts of the program, the string literals are allowed to overlap. I removed the part I thought may suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

TL,DR: pass a string literal as the format string unless you really have no choice.

Is it valid C? Yes, sure. `printf` wants its first argument to be a string (a null-terminated array of characters), and it's getting it. Whatever the value of `x` is, this string contains exactly one printf format, which expects an `int` argument. And `printf` receives an `int` argument. So all is fine, as far as the C language is concerned.

Is it good practice? No. There are several advantages to passing a string literal as the format string to functions like `printf`, `scanf`, etc. If you pass a string literal, that gives the compiler (and other static analyzers) the opportunity to complain if you aren't passing correctly typed arguments. If you pass something more complex, the compiler may not be able to tell. Furthermore, passing a string literal gives the compiler more optimization opportunities: many compilers will break down `printf` calls into lower-level functions when the format string is constant: `printf("%d seconds elapsed", x)` will be compiled into something like `__builtin_printf_int(x) + fputs("", stdout)` (plus error checking). If the format string is variable, it has to be parsed at runtime.

In this simple example, compilers are likely to recognize that there are only two possible format strings and to perform the check and optimization. In fact, let's make the program wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(long x) {
    printf(x == 1 ? "%d second elapsed" : "%d seconds elapsed", x);
}
```

Here's what GCC has to say about it:

```
a.c: In function ‘foo’:
a.c:3:23: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf(x == 1 ? "%d second elapsed" : "%d seconds elapsed", x);
                      ~^
                      %ld
a.c:3:45: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf(x == 1 ? "%d second elapsed" : "%d seconds elapsed", x);
                                            ~^
                                            %ld
```

You're getting two warnings, one for each of the two formats. But in more complex cases, the compiler would give up and just pass the dynamically constructed string to `printf` at runtime, with no opportunity to bail out if the parameters are wrong.

As long as your program hard-codes English for messages, there's a simple solution: make the pluralization a separate argument.

```
printf("%d second%s elapsed", x, x == 1 ? "" : "s");
```

This doesn't work well with internationalization, since different languages have different rules (for example some languages need the singular for 0, some have a different form for 2 and 3-or-more, some need a plural on “elapsed”, etc.). If you need internationalization, you aren't passing a constant string to `printf` anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - I really like your proposed solution.